# 'DisplayAlerts' of object '_Application' failed while updating Powerpoint from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, powerpoint-2010

I'm trying to update charts created in Powerpoint 2010 from data stored in Excel 2010.
I've created the charts in Powerpoint using `Insert Object` and `Create New Microsoft Excel Chart`(you can then right-click the chart and select `Edit Object` to open its data sheet).

Everything works perfectly except one line...

At the end of the code I have `Application.DisplayAlerts = TRUE` to turn notifications back on after I've tidied up `ThisWorkbook` (deleting a sheet) - I turn the notifications off at the start of the procedure as an error is thrown if I do it just before deleting the sheet.
**This is always throwing the error in the question title.**  I thought it could be getting confused over which application I mean - Thisworkbook, Powerpoint or the instance of Excel used in the PPT chart.
I've tried using: `ThisWorkbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = True` & `ThisWorkbook.Parent.DisplayAlerts = True` but with no luck.

Any ideas?

My code is:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Produce_Report()

    Dim sTemplate As String         'Path to PPTX Template.
    Dim sDataFileFullName As String 'Path to raw data XLSX file.
    Dim sDataFileName As String     'The file name without the path.
    Dim wrkBkDataFile As Workbook   'Reference to raw data XLSX file.
    Dim sSheetName As String        'Name of the first sheet in the workbook.
    Dim rDataFileLastCell As Range  'Reference to last cell containing data in raw data.
    Dim WrkSht As Worksheet         'Reference to worksheet in PPTX.
    Dim WrkCht As Chart             'Reference to chart sheet in PPTX.
    Dim oPPT As Object              'Reference to PPT application.
    Dim oPresentation As Object     'Reference to opened presentation.
    Dim oSlide As Object            'Reference to slide in PPT.
    Dim oShape As Object            'Reference to text box in PPT.
    Dim sReportMonth As String      'Text displaying current month.
    Dim sReportYear As String       'Text displaying current year.
    Dim rTemp As Range              'Temporary range object.
    Dim rTemp2 As Range             'Temporary range object.
    Dim WrkSht1 As Worksheet        'Temporary worksheet object.
    Dim WrkSht2 As Worksheet        'Temporary worksheet object.

    sTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PPT Template\My Template.pptx"
    sDataFileFullName = GetFile(ThisWorkbook.Path)
    sDataFileName = Mid(sDataFileFullName, InStrRev(sDataFileFullName, "\") + 1, Len(sDataFileFullName))

    'TODO: Check integrity of sDataFileFullName.
    If sDataFileFullName <> "" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Set oPPT = CreatePPT

        'Open the required files.
        Set oPresentation = oPPT.Presentations.Open(sTemplate)
        Set wrkBkDataFile = Workbooks.Open(sDataFileFullName, UpdateLinks:=False)

        'TODO: Make the worksheet selection more intelligent.
        sSheetName = wrkBkDataFile.Worksheets(1).Name

        Set rDataFileLastCell = LastCell(wrkBkDataFile.Worksheets(sSheetName))

        'Get the month and year from the 'Date_Audited' column.
        sReportMonth = Format(wrkBkDataFile.Worksheets(1).Range("AD2"), "mmmm")
        sReportYear = Format(wrkBkDataFile.Worksheets(1).Range("AD2"), "yyyy")

        '''''''''''''''''''''''
        'MONTHLY TEAM VOLUMES '
        '''''''''''''''''''''''
        Set oSlide = oPresentation.slides(6)
        With oSlide
            With .Shapes("chtReportingReason")
                Set WrkSht = .OLEFormat.Object.Worksheets(1)
                Set WrkCht = .OLEFormat.Object.Charts(1)
            End With
            Set WrkSht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            'Copy data from raw data to the temp sheet.
            With wrkBkDataFile.Worksheets(sSheetName)
                .Range(.Cells(1, 28), .Cells(rDataFileLastCell.Row, 28)).Copy Destination:= _
                    WrkSht1.Cells(1, 1)
            End With
            With WrkSht1
                'Remove duplicates and sort the data fields.
                .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastCell(WrkSht1).Row, 1)).RemoveDuplicates _
                    Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
                Set rTemp2 = LastCell(WrkSht1)
                With .Sort
                    .SortFields.Clear
                    .SortFields.Add Key:=WrkSht1.Range(WrkSht1.Cells(2, 1), WrkSht1.Cells(rTemp2.Row, 1)) _
                        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    .SetRange WrkSht1.Range(WrkSht1.Cells(2, 1), WrkSht1.Cells(rTemp2.Row, 1))
                    .Header = xlYes
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                    .Apply
                End With
                'Add formula to count total entries and total breaches.
                .Range("A1:D1") = Array("", "Total Volume", "Error Volume", "Accurate")
                .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(rTemp2.Row, 2)).FormulaR1C1 = _
                    "=COUNTIF('[" & wrkBkDataFile.Name & "]" & sSheetName & "'!R1C28:R" & rDataFileLastCell.Row & "C28,RC1)"
                .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(rTemp2.Row, 3)).FormulaR1C1 = _
                    "=COUNTIFS('[" & wrkBkDataFile.Name & "]" & sSheetName & "'!R1C28:R" & rDataFileLastCell.Row & "C28,RC1," & _
                              "'[" & wrkBkDataFile.Name & "]" & sSheetName & "'!R1C26:R" & rDataFileLastCell.Row & "C26,TRUE)"
                .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(rTemp2.Row, 4)).FormulaR1C1 = _
                    "=COUNTIFS('[" & wrkBkDataFile.Name & "]" & sSheetName & "'!R1C28:R" & rDataFileLastCell.Row & "C28,RC1," & _
                              "'[" & wrkBkDataFile.Name & "]" & sSheetName & "'!R1C26:R" & rDataFileLastCell.Row & "C26,FALSE)"
                .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(rTemp2.Row, 4)).Value = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(rTemp2.Row, 4)).Value
                'Empty the destination sheet of data and paste the new data in.
                WrkSht.Cells.ClearContents
                .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rTemp2.Row, 4)).Copy Destination:=WrkSht.Range("A1")
            End With
            With WrkSht
                WrkCht.SetSourceData .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rTemp2.Row, 4))
                oPPT.ActiveWindow.viewtype = 7
                RefreshChart oPPT, oSlide.slidenumber, oSlide.Shapes("chtReportingReason")
            End With
            WrkSht1.Delete
            Set WrkSht1 = Nothing
        End With

       ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
       'ERROR HAPPENS EVERY TIME HERE.                      '
       'WILL CONTINUE WITHOUT PROBLEMS IF I PRESS F5 OR F8. '
       ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
       ThisWorkbook.Parent.DisplayAlerts = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Other functions called from the code:

```
Public Function CreatePPT(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTmpPPT As Object

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Defer error trapping in case Powerpoint is not running. '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTmpPPT = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'If an error occurs then create an instance of Powerpoint. '
    'Reinstate error handling.                                 '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTmpPPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    End If

    oTmpPPT.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreatePPT = oTmpPPT

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreatePPT."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function

Public Function LastCell(WrkSht As Worksheet, Optional Col As Long = 0) As Range

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    With WrkSht
        If Col = 0 Then
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        Else
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Columns(Col).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
        End If

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = WrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Function GetFile(Optional startFolder As Variant = -1) As Variant
    Dim fle As FileDialog
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Set fle = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fle
        .Title = "Select a File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*", 1
        If startFolder = -1 Then
            .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        Else
            If Right(startFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
                .InitialFileName = startFolder & "\"
            Else
                .InitialFileName = startFolder
            End If
        End If
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        vItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFile = vItem
    Set fle = Nothing
End Function

Public Sub RefreshChart(oPPT As Object, SlideNum As Long, sh As Object)
    oPPT.ActiveWindow.viewtype = 7
    oPPT.ActiveWindow.View.GoToSlide SlideNum
    oPPT.ActiveWindow.viewtype = 9
    sh.OLEFormat.DoVerb (1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, at the end of the code you have `ThisWorkbook.Parent.DisplayAlerts = True` do you get the same error if it's ***literally*** `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`?

Comment: @Comintern Yes, sorry - should have put all versions in there and commented out the ones I've tried.  I've tried `Application.DisplayAlerts = True`, `ThisWorkbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = True`, `ThisWorkbook.Parent.DisplayAlerts = True` and I'm sure I tried a couple of others but can't think what the syntax would have been.  There's a `=FALSE` line at the start which works, but if I move it to just before I delete the sheet at the bottom it also fails.

Comment: @pnuts I'm not hiding anything, I just want the warning messages turned back on - I turn them off at the start of the procedure (I wanted to turn them off just before I delete the sheet at the end but that throws an error).  I'm starting to think I should leave them off as don't they reset when the code finishes?  BUT.... why's it stop working in the first place?

Comment: @pnuts - I was wondering _"what's he talking about, that doesn't hide notifications"_.  I see what you mean now - I'll reword it.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the simple answer to the question is (something I learnt years ago, but was being lazy and it bit me).... *split your code into separate procedures for readability and to make it easier to reset your variables when required.*

In my original code I had whole sections for each slide in the presentation. The code in my original post just shows the code for one slide.
Writing the code in this way caused another problem - my charts started displaying incorrect data and I couldn't figure why - run the whole code and it mucked up, step through it line by line and it worked.

I split each slide into a separate procedure to solve the error (it worked) and put the `DisplayAlerts` into the main procedure and I no longer get the error message.

```
Option Explicit

Private wrkShtDataFile As Worksheet     'Reference to raw data worksheet.
Private rDataFileLastCell As Range      'Reference to last cell on raw data worksheet.
Private sReportMonth As String          'Text displaying current month.
Private sReportYear As String           'Text displaying current year.

Public Sub Produce_Report()

    Dim sTemplate As String             'Path to PPTX Template.
    Dim sDataFileFullName As String     'Path to raw data XLSX file.
    Dim sDataFileName As String         'The file name without the path.
    Dim oPPT As Object                  'Reference to PPT application.
    Dim oPresentation As Object         'Reference to opened presentation.
    Dim wrkBkDataFile As Workbook       'Reference to raw data XLSX file.
    Dim oSlide As Object                'Reference to slide in PPT.

    sTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PPT Template\Zero Commission Template.pptx"
    sDataFileFullName = GetFile(ThisWorkbook.Path)
    sDataFileName = Mid(sDataFileFullName, InStrRev(sDataFileFullName, "\") + 1, Len(sDataFileFullName))

    If sDataFileFullName <> "" Then

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        'Open the Powerpoint template and save a copy so we can roll back.
        Set oPPT = CreatePPT
        Set oPresentation = oPPT.Presentations.Open(sTemplate)
        oPresentation.SaveCopyAs _
            Left(oPresentation.FullName, InStrRev(oPresentation.FullName, ".") - 1) & " (Previous)"

        Set wrkBkDataFile = Workbooks.Open(sDataFileFullName, UpdateLinks:=False)
        Set wrkShtDataFile = wrkBkDataFile.Worksheets(1)
        Set rDataFileLastCell = LastCell(wrkShtDataFile)

        sReportMonth = Format(wrkShtDataFile.Range("AD2"), "mmmm")
        sReportYear = Format(wrkShtDataFile.Range("AD2"), "yyyy")

        'Add the month and year to the Title slide.
        Set oSlide = oPresentation.slides(1)
        With oSlide
            .Shapes("Report_Date").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sReportMonth & " " & sReportYear
        End With
        Set oSlide = Nothing

'Calls to update slides:
        Audit_Volumes oPresentation.slides(2)
        Monthly_Accuracy_Trends oPresentation.slides(3)
        Monthly_Entry_Type oPresentation.slides(4)
        Reporting_Reason oPresentation.slides(5)
        Monthly_Team_Volumes oPresentation.slides(6)
        NoErrorChart oPresentation.slides(9), "New"
        NoErrorChart oPresentation.slides(12), "Mid-Term"
        NoErrorChart oPresentation.slides(15), "Renewal"
        ErrorTable oPresentation.slides(8), "New"
        ErrorTable oPresentation.slides(11), "Mid-Term"
        ErrorTable oPresentation.slides(14), "Renewal"

        oPresentation.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Reports\Quality Review - Zero Comms Deck " & sReportMonth & " " & sReportYear
        wrkBkDataFile.Close SaveChanges:=False

'This now works:
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End If
End Sub
```